# ListFragment inside a ScrollView Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-listfragment, android-scrollview

Here is my current layout:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ListFragment/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to add a picture just before the fragment, something like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView/>
        <ListFragment/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But, `ListFragment` use a `ListView`, and I want the picture to moves with the `ListView`.
It must work if we replace the `ListView` by a `LinearLayout`, but how can I use a `ListFragment` with a `LinearLayout` instead? Or at least, how can I use a `LinearLayout` as a List?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing such a horrible thing like putting a ListView inside a ScrollView (you will confuse Android's scroll manager), just use the `addHeaderView()` [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) of the ListView, to put a View before all the items.

The so added "header" will scroll away with the items.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a solution! Any idea the way I can call this from the Activity hosting the fragment?

Comment: No... do it in the `onCreateView()` of the Fragment itself. Near the code where you find the ListView by id and start setting the ListView's properties and its Adapter.